# GetManifestResourceNames() sometimes fails after app pool restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool

On rare occasions, the following code returns a corrupted string right after the app pool is recycled.  No exceptions are thrown or caught. Once it starts happening, it will continue to fail until IIS is restarted.

```
try {
    foreach (string resourceName in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
        if (resourceName.Contains(LicenseResourceName))
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

    throw new Exception(" \"" + LicenseResourceName + "\" not found in .GetManifestResourceNames()");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    var logger = new Logging.SqlLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    logger.Error("AsposeLicense Error " + ex);
}
```

Comment: `the following code returns a corrupted string`, a) No it just returns a *stream*. How do you read it? b) What do you mean by *corrupted string*?

Comment: Thanks, Good point.  Actually it returns a _good_ stream that is passed to another method: `Aspose.Cells.License().SetLicense(licenseStream);`
Its the SetLicense() method that throws the exception and emits a portion of the distasteful stream content, which looks like base64 gook.
This code is called thousands of times per day, but only fails after someone does an app pool recycle.  sometimes.

Comment: Has anyone seen problems with GetManifestResourceStream after an App Pool recycle?

Comment: Did you tried ***string assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.' })[0];

    if (assemblyName == "App_GlobalResources")
    {
        foreach (string s in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            //do stuff with the list of resources.
        }
    }***